# Retaining changes of view pager's fragment's layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 3 Fragments, each fragment has its own unique layout. Each Fragment knows which layout to use by getting layout id as parameter in newInstance() method from FragmentActivity that holds ViewPager. This ViewPager is controlled by FragmentStatePagerAdapter called MyPagerAdapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
     ViewPager pager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
       pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {
            case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
            case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }     
         @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            registeredFragments.remove(position);
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }

        public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
            return registeredFragments.get(position);
        }
    }
    public void setBackgroundImage(View view){
        int i = pager.getCurrentItem();
        Fragment page = ((MyPagerAdapter)pager.getAdapter()).getRegisteredFragment(i);
        page.getView().findViewById(R.id.first).findViewById(R.id.button1);
        page.getView().findViewById(R.id.first).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the FirstFragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
            tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

            return v;
        }

        public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

            FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("msg", text);

            f.setArguments(b);

            return f;
        }}
```

first_frag.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:id="@+id/first" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFragFirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tvFragFirst"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="setBackgroundImage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It has more buttons and imagebuttons with onClick methods, but it's not necessary to the question, except that it's important to know that I have many onClick methods similar to setBackgroundImage that change appearance of layout.

the SecondFragment and ThirdFragment is similar, as their layouts.

As you can see the method setBackgroundImage in MainActivity, it changes background image of the fragment. But once its changed, it's not permanent, because as I flip through fragments and return to this first fragment the change isn't saved, but the original layout is shown. I understand that once out of vision, fragment's layout gets destroyed. Is there a way to retain layout changes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling onRetainInstance(true) in the Fragments onCreate() method?

Certainly, one way to solve the problem would be to store in the Activity, the background resources for each fragment such that when the fragments are created, they are initialized correctly. This would also involve storing the background data in a bundle in the onSaveInstanceState() method.

Comment: yeap. didn't help. btw it is "setRetainInstance(true);"